# How would you integrate $3\over x^\frac12$?

Tags: integration

I'm working on a past exam paper and I've reached a point where I need to integrate $3\over(x^\frac12)$, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it since I need to bring it down to a single indices, ($x^a$), and I can't find a way to get rid of the 3 in the equation since making the indices a negative creates a $1\over x^m$ , does anyone know what I'm missing? Maybe I can integrate it without getting rid of the 3?

Comment: **Hint** $\frac{1}{x^a} = x^{-a}$.

Comment: I understand that, but the issue is that I have a 3 on top, not a 1.

Comment: If $\int_0^x f = F(x)$, then $\int_0^x (3f) = 3\int_0^x f = 3F(x)$.

Comment: @user321035 You can multiply both sides of Travis's equation by any constant and the equation still holds. Example $\frac{3}{x^a}=3x^{-a}$

Comment: I got it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}} = 3x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$ \int3x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx = \frac{3x^{-\frac{1}{2} + 1}}{-\frac{1}{2} + 1} + C $$

I hope you can finish this (C is a constant of integration).

Comment: Thanks, it just clicked. I can't actually confirm it as the right answer yet but I'll do that when I get around to it.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Integration is a linear operator so
$$\int \frac3{x^{1/2}}\; dx = 3\int\frac1{x^{1/2}}\; dx$$

and since $\frac1{x^{1/2}} = x^{-1/2}$, you can further rewrite this as
$$3\int x^{-1/2}\; dx$$
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Integration is *linear* in this fashion: If you double or triple the thing you're integrating (the integrand), you double or triple the result.  So just integrate as though you were integrating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, then triple the result.

It is also true that integrating the sum of two (or more) functions yields the same result as adding the integrals of the individual functions.  So you can also view the integral of $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$ as the sum of the integrals of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

P.S. Don't forget to add the constant. :-)